# SQL select from table with an update subquery

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I'm trying to update a table and at the same time (in the same transaction) select from the table and perform a count on one of its columns.

See below for example code. The last 2 querys (the UPDATE and the SELECT) I want to merge them into one query somehow.

```
CREATE TABLE ChildProcesses
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    ParentId INT,
    ProcessIsFinished BIT
);

INSERT INTO ChildProcesses (ParentId, ProcessIsFinished) VALUES (1234, 0);
INSERT INTO ChildProcesses (ParentId, ProcessIsFinished) VALUES (1234, 0);
INSERT INTO ChildProcesses (ParentId, ProcessIsFinished) VALUES (1234, 0);
INSERT INTO ChildProcesses (ParentId, ProcessIsFinished) VALUES (1234, 0);

UPDATE ChildProcesses SET ProcessIsFinished = 1 WHERE Id = 4;

SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS CountProcessesStillRunning
FROM
    ChildProcesses
WHERE
    ParentId = 1234 AND
    ProcessIsFinished = 0;
```

The reason for all of this is, I have a distributed process where my code is running in many places. This code performs processing on my "ChildProcesses" and when they're done they set the "ChildProcesses.ProcessIsFinished" to "1". When all of the child processes have finished I need to perform some cleanup steps, but only when ALL of the child processes have finished and I only want to perform the cleanup steps once. So I'm trying to find a way to both "mark the process as finished" and at the same time "check to see if this was the last child process to finish". If this is the last child process to finish then i'll have that child process perform the cleanup steps.

I thought to have the UPDATE query as a subquery to the SELECT, but I get errors saying that's not allowed. Here's what I tried that's not working:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS CountProcessesStillRunning
FROM
    ChildProcesses
WHERE
    ParentId = (UPDATE ChildProcesses SET ProcessIsFinished = 1 OUTPUT INSERTED.ParentId WHERE Id = 4) AND
    ProcessIsFinished = 0;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What benefit does doing this in a single query provide? Why can't you update, then check for completion?

Comment: Imho this is the wrong approach. If you are only interested to know when all rows are processed you don't need to *count* anything, you simply need to check for the existence any unprocessed row and this does not need to be part of an update transaction.

Comment: the benefit is eliminating the posibility of a "race condition". I'm worried that I might have 2 child processes finish at exactly the same time. They might both perform their "Updates" at the same time, then when they both perform their "SELECT" statements then they'd both think they were the "last" child process to finish. I want to guarentee I only have "one" child process be the "last" child process.

Comment: Or you don't want to start tidy up if it's already started? Ie first that starts tidy up sets a flag somewhere that can be checked effectively locking the code not the data.

Comment: @P.Salmon that's not a bad idea. In the Parent table I could add a column (called say "IsCleanedUp") and use `UPDATE Parent SET IsCleanedUp = 1 OUTPUT DELETED.IsCleanedUp, INSERTED.IsCleanedUp WHERE Id = 1234;` and comparing the previous value with the new value would tell me which child process was the one to update that value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took inspiration from @CharlieFace on this one.

I was originally trying to `SELECT` with a subquery having `UPDATE...OUTPUT`, which isn't allowed.

However, I can `UPDATE...OUTPUT...INTO` a temporary table. So I decided to `UPDATE` all ChildProcesses but use a `CASE` to just update my particular ChildId. Then output all of those modified entries into a temporary table. This temporary table I could then compute if all child processes had completed or if there were still running child processes.

Here's the new query.

```
DECLARE @ParentId INT = 1234;
DECLARE @ChildId INT = 1;
DECLARE @Output TABLE (Id INT, ParentId INT, ProcessIsFinished BIT);


UPDATE
    ChildProcesses
SET
    ProcessIsFinished =
        CASE Id
        WHEN @ChildId THEN 1     -- update only 'this' child process
        ELSE ProcessIsFinished   -- leave the other entries alone
        END
OUTPUT
    INSERTED.*
INTO
    @Output
WHERE
    ParentId = @ParentId;


SELECT
    COUNT(*) As StillHasRunningChildProcesses
FROM
    @Output
WHERE
    ProcessIsFinished = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot nest `UPDATE...OUTPUT` except inside a `INSERT...SELECT`, you are not allowed a bare `SELECT` and you are not allowed to group.

Instead you can use a table variable

```sql
DECLARE @output TABLE (ParentId int);

UPDATE ChildProcesses
SET ProcessIsFinished = 1
OUTPUT inserted.ParentId
  INTO @output (ParentId)
WHERE Id = 4;

SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS CountProcessesStillRunning
FROM
    ChildProcesses cp
JOIN
    @output u ON u.ParentId = cp.ParentId
WHERE
    cp.ProcessIsFinished = 0;
```

To avoid race conditions, you might want a transaction. To enure you lock the `ParentId` rows that you are going to read afterwards, use a `SELECT` with a `UPDLOCK` and a `SERIALIZABLE` hint

```sql
SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN TRAN;

DECLARE @dummy int;
SELECT
    @dummy = COUNT(*)
FROM
    ChildProcesses cp
JOIN ChildProcesses cp2 WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)
    ON cp2.ParentId = cp.ParentId
WHERE
    cp.Id = 4;


DECLARE @output TABLE (ParentId int);

UPDATE ChildProcesses WITH (SERIALIZABLE)
SET ProcessIsFinished = 1
OUTPUT inserted.ParentId
  INTO @output (ParentId)
WHERE Id = 4;


SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS CountProcessesStillRunning
FROM
    ChildProcesses cp
JOIN
    @output u ON u.ParentId = cp.ParentId
WHERE
    cp.ProcessIsFinished = 0;

COMMIT;
```

---

If `ParentId` is actually the primary key for this table, and you just want the number of rows affected then you can just use `@@ROWCOUNT`. It doesn't seem that you actually want this logic, but you should get the idea.

```sql
UPDATE ChildProcesses
SET ProcessIsFinished = 1
WHERE Id = 4
  AND ProcessIsFinished = 0;

SELECT
    @@ROWCOUNT AS CountProcessesStillRunning;
```

Comment: This still doesn't get me what i'm looking for, which is "updating a single ChildProcess entry AND in the same query getting the state of all ChildProcess entries contained in the ParentProcess". However, you did give me an idea. I'd forgotten you can `UPDATE...OUTPUT...INTO` a temporary table. Please see my edited answer, which solves what I was looking for.

Comment: The first half of my answer is exactly thatt, is it not?

Comment: Your query would still have a race condition, would it not? say for example ChildId = 1 and 2 had already finished, and that ChildId = 3 and 4 finished last at exactly the same time. The `UPDATE` statements might run first for both ChildId = 3 and 4, then the `SELECT` statements would both run last. This would result in the `SELECT` statement yielding `CountProcessesStillRunning = 0` for both of the ChildId = 3 and 4, right? Which would mean ChildId = 3 and 4 would both think that they were the last process to finish which is what I want to avoid.

Comment: OK given you a solution for that